# How to get UEFI Secure Boot devices to PXE boot?

Tags: drbl, central-processing-unit, pxe-boot

I have HP ElitePad 900's and Acer Iconia W510's which are not allowed to boot linux. Is there a way to boot them in network using grub2, ipxe, ... to detect them being Atom get a menu to redirect them to WinPE by default while booting other devices to my existing drbl clonezilla server?

My main goal is to get one server to provide all kinds of boot options (with the focus on disk imaging so most importantly Clonezilla Live & WinPE with automated DISM).

Answer (score -1):

I guess this devices can boot from USB so gPXE might be the answer. Check this out:

http://etherboot.org/wiki/howtos